# stuck on login screen, with Ctrl + alt +Fx not working

Tags: upgrade, login-screen

I tried upgrading my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 through the terminal but it got to a point when my laptop froze so I had to switch it off and restart it but now when I enter my login details, nothing happens; plus the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys too don't work. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome on AskUbuntu. :-) Can you remember the command and the last line(s) of output when you had to reset the machine? And the login screen reacts to nothing, it is just frozen?

Comment: An error occured during upgrade and the system is broken now - that's why I'm always saying "a clean new install is better than upgrade".

Comment: Can't seem to recall the last command, but for the login screen after entering the password, the only thing that works is the Esc key which only allows me to reenter the password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot a live USB and boot into "Try Ubuntu" option. Make sure you are connected the net
2. open the terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> )  or enter tty ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ) and do the following

   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

   sudo chroot /mnt

   apt-get update

   apt-get upgrade

   3. Reboot

Let us know of any errors or whether or not it helped.

Note: if this process doesn't help, repeat steps 1. and 2. , and in addition to that do

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

You will be prompted to choose default greeter, so choose gdm.

In case that also fails, repeat steps 1. and 2., and do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```